# How to create a column of "day of week" based on the dates?

Tags: r, sparkr

I have a Spark `data.frame` with a column of `POSIXct` data and I want to convert it to another column to show the day of week. How can I do this in [`SparkR`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html)? I know in **R** I can use `weekdays()` or other packages like `lubridate` to do this, but these functions and packages cannot be directly applied to Spark `data.frame` unless I am missing something. Can anybody help please?

Comment: in SparkSQL / sparkR it's `date_format(posixct_column_name, 'E')` : https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/95eb06bd7d0f7110ef62c8d1cb6337c72b10d99f/R/pkg/R/generics.R which uses http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html syntax. (add more `E`'s for longer names)

Comment: cool! It worked. Thank you! And also, for https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/95eb06bd7d0f7110ef62c8d1cb6337c72b10d99f/R/pkg/R/generics.R  , could you briefly explain what these are and how to use them, please? Thanks!

Comment: Those are the SparkSQL functions that are exposed in `sparkR`. Basically, that list is what is possible to call function-wise for data transformations on the Spark-side by default. Many of them are similar to R function names (I think somewhat on purpose tho many are "generic" like "max").